# ReactJS not loading elements on first gen iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, reactjs

I've got a first gen iPad for tablet screen testing and react won't load my components in either Safari or Chrome. My iPhone 4s loads fine as do the browsers on my desktop environments. Am I missing a compatibility report or something? I can't seem to find a reference to it in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have a first-gen iPad; I was able to get my apps to work by loading an [ES5 shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim). There is some more information on the React site under [Browser Support and Polyfills](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html#browser-support-and-polyfills).